# How to move a folder structure into Draftcode PHP IDE for iOS?

Tags: php, ios, ios8

There is Draftcode (http://freeridecoding.com/draftcode/) which allows to do PHP development on an iPad. How can I import a complete folder structure with PHP code into Draftcode for execution there? iOS 8 is very strict about inter-app communications, and I cannot find a way to move files into Draftcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Draftcode executes PHP code: Type and execute a script in Draftcode that downloads and installs the desired files.

Sample script that downloads a zipped archive containing the entire folder structure with all files, and unpacks it within Draftcode:

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents ("http://website.nl/file.zip");
file_put_contents ("file.zip", $contents);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open ("file.zip");
$zip->extractTo (__DIR__);
$zip->close ();
?>
```